# How to freeze a Solana token using @solana/web3.js

Tags: web3.js, freeze-token-account

I have minted a token following this guide:
https://www.quicknode.com/guides/web3-sdks/how-to-create-a-fungible-spl-token-with-the-new-metaplex-token-standard
I have also set my own public key to be the freeze authority. I now wish to freeze the token.
My current approach is:

```
let transaction: Transaction = new Transaction().add(createFreezeAccountInstruction(nft.mintKeypair.publicKey, nft.mintKeypair.publicKey, kp.publicKey))
await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [kp])
```

Where `nft.mintKeypair.publicKey` is the mint address of my token, and `kp` is my own keypair that I have used as the freeze authority.
When I send this transaction and sign it with my keypair I am presented with
`Program log: Error: InvalidAccountData`
What am I doing wrong? How can I freeze this token?

Comment: The method signature of `createFreezeAccountInstruction` in `@solana/spl-token` from version 0.2.0 onward looks consistent with how you've used it here.

`function createFreezeAccountInstruction(account: PublicKey, mint: PublicKey, authority: PublicKey, multiSigners: Signer[] = [], programId = TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID): TransactionInstruction;`

It _used_ to look different before that. Follow up questions: what version do you have installed? Do you have Typescript enabled in your project? Which signature appears when you hover over the method call in your editor?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's gone over a year without a follow up. If this is still relevant, let's get some more detail!